# FOL: theorem proving

Tags: first-order-logic

The following are axioms and theorems of group theory:

Axiom 1: $(\forall x)(\forall y)(\forall z)(x \,
\circ\,(y\, \circ \,z) = (x \, \circ \,y)\,\circ\,z)$

Axiom 2: $(\forall x)(x \, \circ \, e = x)$

Axiom 3: $(\forall x)(x \, \circ \, x^{-1} = e) $

Theorem 1 (Right hand cancellation):

$$(\forall x)(\forall y)(\forall z)(x \, \circ \, z \, = \, y \, \circ \,z \, \rightarrow \, x = y)$$

Theorem 2 (Commutativity of Identity): $$(\forall x)(x \, \circ \, e \, = \, e \, \circ \, x)$$

Theorem 3 (Uniqueness of Identity):

$$(\forall y)[(\forall x)(x \, \circ \, y \, = \, x) \rightarrow \, y \, = \, e]$$

Theorem 4 (Commutativity of Inverse):

$$(\forall x)(x \, \circ \, x^{-1}= \, x^{-1} \circ \, x)$$

Theorem 5 (Left-hand cancellation):

$$(\forall x)(\forall y)(\forall z)(z \, \circ \, x \, = \, z \, \circ \,y \, \rightarrow \, x = y)$$

Theorem 6 (Uniqueness of Inverse):

$$(\forall x)(\forall y)(x \, \circ \, y \, = e \rightarrow y=x^{-1})$$

Theorem 7 (idk the name):

$$(\forall x)((x^{-1})^{-1}=x)$$

With only these, I'm asked to prove the theorem:

$$(\forall x)(\forall y)(\exists z)(x = y\,\circ\,z)$$

In my attempt I start with none of the axioms and theorems but rather I try to use the fact that all valid interpretations of the operator, $\circ$, satisfies the closure property. That is, I start with the statement

$(\forall x)(\forall y)(\exists z)(x \,\circ\,y=z)$

Roughly, I proceed as follows...

$(1) \>\>(\forall x)(\forall y)(\exists z)(x \,\circ\,y=z)$ premise

$(2) \>\>(\exists z)(x \,\circ\,y=z)$ by US

$(3) \>\>x \,\circ\,y= \alpha_{xy}\>$ by ES

$(4) \>\>x \,\circ\,y=\alpha_{xy} \circ e\>$ by axiom 2

$(5) \>\>x \,\circ\,y=\alpha_{xy} \circ (y \circ y^{-1})\>$ by axiom 3

$(6) \>\>x \,\circ\,y=\alpha_{xy} \circ (y^{-1} \circ y)\>$ by theorem 4

$(7) \>\>x \,\circ\,y=(\alpha_{xy} \circ y^{-1}) \circ y\>$ by axiom 1

$(8) \>\>x =\alpha_{xy} \circ y^{-1}\>$ by theorem 1

$(9) \>\>(\exists z)(x =z \circ y^{-1})\>$ by EG

Now here I'm stuck. Intuitively, I think a valid deduction would obtained from applying universal generalisation on $y^{-1}$ to yield

$(10) \>\>(\forall y)(\exists z)(x =z \circ y)\>$ by UG on $y^{-1}$

because firstly, $y$ doesn't appear anywhere else in formula. Secondly, since y can be anything in the domain, $y^{-1}$ can be anything in the domain as well (unless I'm mistaken). My idea is something like substituting a variable to act as $y^{-1}$ and to universally generalise on that variable.

However, $y^{-1}$ is strictly defined as term rather than a variable, and in no part of the textbook I'm reading does it explain that such a move is valid. The rule for UG I'm given is defined only for variables rather than for terms in general.

Maybe I'm approaching it the wrong way. I would appreciate any hints :)

Comment: It works... $y^{-1}$ is a term but the "inverse" operation is a *function* symbol of the language. Thus, it is simply $y \circ f(y) = e$, where $e$ is an individual constant. Thus, the above is a formula whatever, and we can "generalize" on $y$ to get $\forall y (y \circ f(y) = e)$.